# Problema em aplicar animate CSS

Tags: animate.css

Estou tentando implementar o recurso do Animate.css como mostra nessa documentação abaixo.

[ANIMATE.CSS](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

Não estou conseguindo implementar esse recurso, eu fiz o passo a passo e não funcionou.

Eu não coloquei a importação de jquery da documentação, eu coloquei essas;

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Coloquei o arquivo animate.css no projeto como vocês podem ver;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Completei a implementação no botão;

```
.logo{
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    -vendor-animation-duration: 3s;
    -vendor-animation-delay: 2s;
    -vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Em seguida configurei o botão;

```
 <div class="logo animated bouce">
                <img src="img/logofinal2.png"  height="150" >
        </div>
```

Porém não aconteceu nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara vc está usando alguma coisas errado, por exemplo onde está *vendor* vc deveria colocar o prefixo de uma vez, tipo `-ms-`, `-o-` ou `-webkit-` No exemplo que fiz com o seu código original só acrescentei o `-webkit-`nos estilos da animação. Outra coisa vc pode colocar o `infinite` direto na tag do elemento na `class=""`, então não precisa colocar `animation-iteration-count:infinite`, 
EX: `<h1 class="animated infinite bounce logo">Example</h1>`

Veja a estrutura do animete.css como fica junto do Bootstrap4 que é o que vc está usando. 
**OBS:** Lembro ainda que não necessariamente vc precisa de JS ou jQuery para usa o animate.css, pois como o nome diz ele é puro css não tem scripts...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<style>
.logo{
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1 class="animated infinite bounce logo">Example</h1>
    <div class="animated infinite bounce logo">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100"  height="150" >
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```